# Sublinear Inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, inequality, absolute-value, functional-inequalities

For $f(x,y)=x^2/y$, is it possible to prove that $$f(x_1,y_1)-f(x_2,y_2)\le Cf(x_1-x_2,y_1-y_2)$$ 
or
$$|f(x_1,y_1)-f(x_2,y_2)|\le C|f(x_1-x_2,y_1-y_2)|$$ with $0< x_k,y_k \le M<\infty$, $k=1,2$, where $C$ is a positive constant?  Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

The following is true
\begin{eqnarray*}
0 \leq (x_1 y_2 - x_2 y_1)^2.
\end{eqnarray*}
Rearrange & create some terms 
\begin{eqnarray*}
&x_1^2y_1y_2 - x_1^2y_2^2 &-x_2^2y_1^2 +x_2^2y_1y_2  &\leq x_1^2y_1y_2 - 2x_1x_2y_1y_2 +x_2^2y_1y_2, \\
&x_1^2 y_2(y_1-y_2)&-x_2^2y_1(y_1-y_2) &\leq (x_1-x_2)^2 y_1 y_2.
\end{eqnarray*}
Now assume $y_1 > y_2 >0 $,so we can divide by $y_1y_2(y_1-y_2)$ and we have 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{x_1^2}{y_1}  -\frac{x_2^2}{y_2}  \leq \frac{(x_1-x_2)^2 }{y_1- y_2} .
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: This is an excellent answer.  Thank you so much!